# Error during a simple typecast

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, inheritance, type-conversion

I have made a custom class:

```
class fpCellEnum : FarPoint.Win.Spread.Cell, IEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Cell>
{
    public IEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Cell> AsEnumerable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Cell> source)
    {
        return source;
    }
}
```

I need the above class so that i can use Linq on Cells of a FarPoint sheet. But i get the following error on this code:

```
fpCellEnum fp = new fpCellEnum();
IEnumerator<fpCellEnum> iEnCells = ((fpCellEnum)fpSpread1.ActiveSheet.Cells[0,0,fpSpread1.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count,fpSpread1.ActiveSheet.Columns.Count]).AsEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Cell>();
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: did you mean `IEnumerable<fpCellEnum>`?

Comment: 1) That's not how extension methods work. 2) I think you've misunderstood something about generics. 3) It's really unclear how you expect to convert a `Cell` to an `fpCellEnum`.

Comment: Why do you need the `AsEnumerable<TSource>()` method when the containing class is already of the returned type (and you don't use the generic `TSource` at all)?

Answer (score 1):

IEnumerable and IEnumerator are not the same. You can get an IEnumerator from IEnumerable using the `.GetEnumerator()` method.

```
IEnumerator<fpCellEnum> iEnCells = ((fpCellEnum)fpSpread1.ActiveSheet.Cells[0,0,fpSpread1.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count,fpSpread1.ActiveSheet.Columns.Count]).AsEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Cell>().GetEnumerator();
```

However, you have a bigger problem as to how you expect to convert `Cell` to `fpCellEnum` in your generics.